# How to transform a non-stationary time series with short spikes to stationary?

Tags: data-transformation, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I used ADF test to test stationarity:

```
ADF Statistic: -7.8345728860708865
p-value: 6.163993342051128e-12
Critical Values:
    1%: -3.4317832926440612
    5%: -2.8621733470784583
    10%: -2.56710713369859
```

The p-value is very high, so I can't reject the null hypothesis. Then I applied log transformation to my dataset. Here is the ADF results:

```
ADF Statistic: -5.96668063663575
p-value: 1.98016390368094e-07
Critical Values:
    1%: -3.431782350810031
    5%: -2.8621729309985806
    10%: -2.5671069122000763
```

Even so, the p-value is much larger than 0.05.

Finally I tried to use differencing:

```
ADF Statistic: -5.375440230205101
p-value: 3.813633376803356e-06
Critical Values:
    1%: -3.4319060752453483
    5%: -2.862227588385493
    10%: -2.567136009040254
```

My time series plotted:

[image: plot]

Why the p-value is so high? Is it because of the short spikes?

How can I make my time series stationary?

**EDIT**: I had not realized that the p-value is in scientific notation, so my p-value < 0.05

Comment: "The p-value is very high, so I can't reject the null hypothesis" Incorrect, your p-value is very low. The negative value of the ADF test is more negative than the 1% criterion. Your series is already stationary. You might have reason to consider adjusting for seasonality, however.

Comment: @John, oh sorry my bad. I had not realized that the p-value is in scientific notation

Comment: No worries. Happens to the best of us.